# Pyspark: filter contents of array inside row

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

In Pyspark, one can filter an array using the following code:

```
lines.filter(lambda line: "some" in line)
```

But I have read data from a json file and tokenized it. Now it has the following form:

```
df=[Row(text=u"i have some text", words=[u'I', u'have', u"some'", u'text'])]
```

How can I filter out "some" from words array ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_contains`, it's available since 1.4 :

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(text=u"i have some text", words=[u'I', u'have', u'some', u'text'])])

df.withColumn("keep", F.array_contains(df.words,"some")) \
  .filter(F.col("keep")==True).show()
# +----------------+--------------------+----+
# |            text|               words|keep|
# +----------------+--------------------+----+
# |i have some text|[I, have, some, t...|true|
# +----------------+--------------------+----+
```

If you want to filter out 'some', like I said in the comment, you can use the `StopWordsRemover` API

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StopWordsRemover

StopWordsRemover(inputCol="words", stopWords=["some"]).transform(df)
```

Comment: but how can i filter out "some" from words?

Comment: you can either apply stop words removal or just filter it out apply an udf